# NSAttributedString GetBoundingRect using character wrap not word wrap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsattributedstring

I am attempting to calculate the bounding rect for a `NSAttributedString` and then put that attributed string into a `UITextView`. I want to size the `UITextView` base on the the text. The reason I want to calculate manually is because this `UITextView` is in a `UITableViewCell` and I don't want to use automatic dimension on my cell heights.

```
string myString = "This is some test string that should be long enough to be word wrapped";

var boldAttributes = new UIStringAttributes ();
boldAttributes.ForegroundColor = UIColor.Black;
boldAttributes.Font = AppDelegate.SegoeUIBold.WithSize (14);

var attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString (myString, boldAttributes);

var rect = attributedString.GetBoundingRect(new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 16, 10000), NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, null);
var height = Math.Ceiling(rect.Height);
```

This works most of the time. However there are some special cases where it fails. In this case I have a string of text that would get broken up into 3 lines.

> This is some test string that should 
>  be long enough to be word
>   
>  wrapped.

So my `GetBoundingRect` should return a height big enough for 3 lines. But it only returns a height big enough for 2 lines. I've found that If I change the `UITextViews` wrapping to character wrapping everything seems to work fine. So my string looks like this in the end:

> This is some test string that should b
> e long enough to be word
>   wrapped.

I can't figure out how to get `attributedString.GetBoundingRect()` to do word wrapping instead of character wrapping. Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this one:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        nfloat padding = 70;
        nfloat tfWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 2 * padding;

        string myString = "This is some test string that should be long enough to be word wrapped";

        UILabel tf = new UILabel (new CGRect (padding,100,tfWidth,0));
        tf.Text = myString;
        tf.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        tf.Lines = int.MaxValue;
        tf.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        tf.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(14);
        this.View.AddSubview (tf);

        NSString nsStr = new NSString(myString);
        nfloat height = nsStr.GetBoundingRect (
            new CoreGraphics.CGSize (tfWidth,float.MaxValue),
            NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading,
            new UIStringAttributes (){Font = tf.Font},
            null).Size.Height;
        tf.Frame = new CGRect (tf.Frame.Location, new CGSize (tfWidth, height));
    }
```

And in UITableViewSource, I use this code:

```
    public override nfloat GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CellItem item = dataList [indexPath.Row];
        NSString nsStr = new NSString(item.Message);
        nfloat textWidth = item.CellWidth;
        nfloat height = nsStr.GetBoundingRect (
            new CoreGraphics.CGSize (textWidth,float.MaxValue),
            NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading,
            new UIStringAttributes (){Font = item.Font},
            null).Size.Height;
            return height;
    }
```

You can use different Font for each cell if you want.

Hope it can help you.